# EF 6.1 Index IsUnique not being generated

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have the following code first entity:

```
class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index("NameIndex", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But on checking the database with SQL Management Studio, there are multiple rows of the same name:

```
ID=1, Name=admin
ID=2, Name=admin
```

My context is very simple:

```
class MemberContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Checking the SQL 2014 Express database table indexes, none are generated (only the PK exists).

Is there anything I have not done that is required for Index to work?

Comment: Is this an enhancement?  Is so how are you updating the database DDL?  Are you using EF Migrations?

Comment: Hi @RichardSchneider, I am making a new EF 6.1 database with only the above code - am i missing something during DbContext creation that I need to override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was writing a new class (that was being injected from a DLL by Autofac) and the main program was running EF 6.0 (whereas my utility class project was using EF 6.1).

**Specifically, I had to put a length constraint on the string length otherwise i wouldn't be able to  put an index on it (indexes cannot be generated on varchar(max)):**

```
class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(127)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }       

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The answer is precisely that an index cannot be created on a varcahr(max) column. Modify it, an accept as the correct answer (I know it's your own answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think your database has already been created and now you are trying to change the model.  I could tell you to just delete the database and re-run you code, but this would mean losing all your data.

You should really read about [EF Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj193542.aspx) and then implement it.

However, you will still have an issue.  In that your existing data cannot be upgraded because of the new uniqueness constraint on Name.

**UPDATE 1**

On re-reading your question, "there are multiple rows of the same **username**".  You show us the code for Role **NOT** Users.  Have you applied the constraint to Users?

**UPDATE 2**

If you're cool to loose data, then do `context.Database.Initialize(true);` in your startup logic.

Comment: Sorry was a typo which has been corrected - I also have a users table which has the same issue. This is not a migrations project and i make sure the database is completely removed by SQL Studio before running the app (im cool to loose data this is just test code at the moment). Please let me know if any other logs that would be useful