# Entity Framework's "Index" decoration is not creating an Index

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is the super simple class I'm trying to create.

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(254)")]
    [Index]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int stupidField { get; set; }
}
```

My goal was to force `Name` to be unique, so I added the decoration `[Index(IsUnique = true)]`. But no unique index was created, so I figured I'll first try to solve the simpler problem of creating any index. Because I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710647/ef-6-1-index-isunique-not-being-generated) that indices cannot be created for columns of type `varchar(max)`, I limited the length of the `Name` field. Still no luck. I even tried a few different syntaxes for limiting the length of the field, but still no index.

To see if something other than string length was at play, I created the integer field `stupidField`, but I can't index that field either. So now I'm completely out of ideas as to what could be wrong. Please help me!

[Check out this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E9tz.png) from MS SQL Server Management Studio that shows that my fields are being created but not the indices.

**Note: I'm certain migrations are not the issue.**
Some of the people I've read about on SO were updating their classes, but those changes were not reflected in the database because of problems with their migrations. That is not relevant here. I delete the database and recreate it every time I make a change. (I even make silly changes like renaming my fields, just to make sure that I can still affect the database.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm actually using Entity Framework Core, not Entity Framework. In Entity Framework Core, indices cannot be created using attributes, although they can be created using fluent API. [See Microsoft's documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes)